# What genre or other singer matches the chorus of "Dream State..." by Lucy Dacus?

Tags: rock, identify-this-genre, indie

In the chorus of her song [Dream State...](https://open.spotify.com/track/6tp18AVA4FEjFTYaSD8exB) Lucy Dacus sings in a deep, monotone drone over guitar, peaking with a chorus of her own voice layered over itself several times...

I know there is at least one other artist that sounds just like this. I would just listen to the rest of Lucy's album to keep getting this fix, but it doesn't really sound the same. I want to hear more of this forlorn droning! It's like on the tip of my tongue but I can't place where I've heard this style before. Help!

She sings the chorus twice; the first time is practically acoustic and the second time features the layering, etc--from 2:15 to the end of the song. Basically the song builds quickly starting at 2:15 and crescendos.

(I don't see a studio version of the song on YouTube; the link is to the track on Spotify)

I've been looking around to see if there's something in particular I've heard before that the song evokes, and I still haven't found anything that I go "a-ha! That's it!" Nonetheless, I think Jay Som, Mitski, or Japanese Breakfast sound somewhat similar.

...After looking a little more, I think this song is pretty similar in terms of how it evokes that sense of psychological tension or longing, if not exactly in other ways...https://open.spotify.com/track/6uaWRTGqadohCbGwo9EVSD

Comment: Could you add a timestamped link?  I listened to the song, and it wasn't clear to me what part matched your description.

Comment: Don't think timestamping is supported by Spotify anymore but I put a link to the song and an indication of the timeframe (2:15-3:30).